# Custom linear operators in ViennaCL

Tags: viennacl

Is is possible to pass custom linear operators (like CUSP's http://cusplibrary.github.io/classcusp_1_1linear__operator.html) to ViennaCL's solvers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for iterative solvers. An example can be found in 
examples/tutorial/matrix-free.cpp or here:
http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/doc/matrix-free_8cpp-example.html